# MS Dynamics audit history for all accounts between dates

Tags: c#, loops, microsoft-dynamics

I have this code which will extract audit history details of the specific Guid mentioned (see second commented line):

```
//Create a new RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest  
RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest req = new RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest();

//Set the target Entity......... Needs to be modified so ALL account records are returned instead of the specific one  mentioned              
req.Target = new EntityReference("accounts", new Guid("468f8db5-4f98-eb11-57ee-0006ffc2587a"));

//Set the attribute you want to retrieve specifically........ needs to be modified so that only records between two dates are returned              
req.AttributeLogicalName = "credit_limit";

//Execute the request against the OrgService

RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryResponse resp = (RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryResponse)_service.Execute(req);

AuditDetailCollection details = resp.AuditDetailCollection;

foreach (var detail in details.AuditDetails)
{
    if (detail.GetType() == typeof(AttributeAuditDetail))
    {
         AttributeAuditDetail attributeDetail = (AttributeAuditDetail)detail;

     }
}
```

I need to modify this so that it loops through ALL account records  that are created between two dates (ex: April 1st to April 7th inclusively) instead of the one specific Guid provided. There are no samples provided by Microsoft that can do this.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code shall work, maybe typo from my side but shall work

```
// Define Condition Values
var query_createdon = "2020-07-15T00:00:00+02:00";
var query_createdon1 = "2021-02-12T00:00:00+01:00";

// Instantiate QueryExpression query
var query = new QueryExpression("account");

// Add columns to query.ColumnSet
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("createdon", "name", "accountid");

// Define filter query.Criteria
query.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, query_createdon);
query.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.LessThan, query_createdon1);

EntityCollection _accounts = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

foreach(var _account in _accounts.Entities){
//Create a new RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest  
RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest req = new RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest();

//Set the target Entity......... Needs to be modified so ALL account records are returned instead of the specific one  mentioned              
req.Target = new EntityReference("accounts", _account.Id);

//Set the attribute you want to retrieve specifically........ needs to be modified so that only records between two dates are returned              
req.AttributeLogicalName = "credit_limit";

//Execute the request against the OrgService

RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryResponse resp = (RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryResponse)_service.Execute(req);

AuditDetailCollection details = resp.AuditDetailCollection;

foreach (var detail in details.AuditDetails)
{
    if (detail.GetType() == typeof(AttributeAuditDetail))
    {
         AttributeAuditDetail attributeDetail = (AttributeAuditDetail)detail;

         var recordID = "(no value)";
         var recordName = "(no value)";
         var changedBy = "(no value)";

         if (attributeDetail.OldValue.Contains("credit_limit"))
///          need to set the value of recordID in here but I don't know how
///          need to set the value of recordName in here but I don't know how
///          need to set the value of changedBy in here but I don't know how
             Console.WriteLine("Record ID: "+recordID);    /// returns (no value) because I don't know how to get the recordID value
             Console.WriteLine("Record Name: "+recordName);    /// returns (no value) because I don't know how to get the recordName value
             Console.WriteLine("Changed By: "+changedBy);    /// returns (no value) because I don't know how to get the changed by value
     }
}

}
```

In short what you need is  two dates in between and get all the accounts. Once you have all those accounts you need to loop through and then get audit history of each those accounts.

Note: If you are fetching more than 5K records you might want to look into paging because bydefault crm retrives only 5k records

```
// Define Condition Values
var query_createdon = "2020-07-15T00:00:00+02:00";
var query_createdon1 = "2021-02-12T00:00:00+01:00";

// Instantiate QueryExpression query
var query = new QueryExpression("account");

// Add columns to query.ColumnSet
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("createdon", "name", "accountid");

// Define filter query.Criteria
query.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, query_createdon);
query.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.LessThan, query_createdon1);

EntityCollection _accounts = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```